# Discriminator field and data modeling

Tags: oop, design-patterns, model, domain-driven-design

I have the following case.

A reservation, this reservation be canceled, it can be newly created it can be Confirmed it can be rejected.

There might be different reasons for cancelation. Lets say the reservation has expired, or it may have not been processed within certain timelimit or some other reason.

In order for a reservation to be confirmed a multiple sub - transactions should be performed. This mean that there is a flow within the Confirmation itself. The solution my team came with is some sort of work table holding many different statuses. Which is fine. I felt the need to uniquely identify the state of a reservation by declaring a field ReservationStatus that depicts certain variation of statuses that are already defined in the table. In this case the Reservation status would be NEW,CONFIRMED,CANCELED,REJECTED. Each state will depict certain variation of statuses in the work table.

My team was convinced that this is adding additional complexity. I think this is the opposite it simplifyes the flow. It also declares a natural discriminator and polymorphism. We are supposed to use Queues and asynchroneus processes.

How can I actualy jsutify that we should have such column it apears the arguments I already mentioned were not enough and deep down inside I know I am right :)?

Comment: Ask your team these questions: "Will the business need to know the Status of a Reservation?  If so, how will we do that?".  If you don't know the answer to the first question, go and ask the business.  Then, see what solutions the team comes up with for the 2nd question.  You should all converge upon the answer.

Comment: @VijayPatel I think it is not only business case here. If we are supposed to write asynchoneus services , one way of doing it is through Events. And Events in my opinion means good typing. One way to bring strong typing is by defining a discriminator I believe. But either I am not explaining it well or I am in a delusion :)

Comment: What fields you add to your entities depends on the business rules/invariants; what are the business rules? I.e. "a cancelled reservation cannot be confirmed anymore"

Comment: Correct, canceled can not be confermed. New can be confirmed or canceled or rejected by client.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov: I can see your point of view, but your team needs a more scientific answer.  Maybe your team have a simpler solution for tracking the Status?
Here's another way to derive the answer: What happens if you *don't* add a Status discriminator?  Will be business be in a better position, or worse?  You've tagged your question with 'domain-driven-design', which is why I keep mentioning 'the business'...

Answer (score 2):

Wanted this to be a comment but it came out too long so here it goes.

@AlexandarPetrov I would add the following questions:

- Do all the Statuses concretely represent every State a Reservation could have?
- Are there clear rules for all Status migration paths? For e.g. Expired -> CONFIRMED and so forth.
- Do you need to model the state changes? And is it a finite state machine?

I'd personally expose the status field but only if it is concrete enough by itself to define state. For e.g. I've seen cases where there are 2 layers of statuses - status and sub-status. In a case like that boundaries are lost and state becomes a complex VO rather than a simple field and state transition rules could become blurry.

**Additionally:**
For me it seems like Event Sourcing and CQRS could be a good fit for all those Reservations. Especially having in mind the complex flows you mention. Then transitions will be events being applied and the statuses - a simple way to expose state. Tracking status changes separately will also be needless as the Event Stream holds all historical data.

**Finally:**

> How can I actualy jsutify that we should have such column it apears the arguments I already mentioned were not enough and deep down inside I know I am right :)?

Well at the end you can always put your foot down and take responsibility. And if it turns out to be a wrong decision in time - bare the responsibility and admit the mistake.

Comment: +1 Event Sourcing and CQRS.  But @AlexandarPetrov's team might lose the plot, if they think adding a discriminator column is 'additional complexity'...

Comment: +1 from me as well. And yes @VijayPatel it is a little bit sad realy to think of discriminator as complexity.